# How to drag or move a span into the Div by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag

How to move or drag the span into the Div element. My element structure is the Div -> Span. Here I need to drag the Span inside the div element without drag beyond that div. I have tried this by calculating pixels but didn't give a solution. I don't need a native onDrag method.

I need to calculate pixels and drag the Span inside the Div. Here is my code.

```js
var handleClick = false;

window.dragging = function(event) {
  if (handleClick) {
    var bar = document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0],
      handle = document.getElementsByClassName('handle')[0];
    var left = bar.offsetWidth - handle.offsetWidth;
    tops = (bar.offsetWidth - handle.offsetWidth);
    pixel = left < ((pixel - 0) / 1.233445) ? left : ((pixel - 0) / 1.233445);
    handle.style.left = pixel + "px";
  }
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  handleClick = false;
});

window.handlersDown = function() {
  handleClick = true;
}
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.handle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 2px;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <span class="handle" onmousedown="handlersDown()" onmousemove="dragging(event)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using any external libs? If not, then take a look at [jQueryUI's Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: I need to do this with **JavaScript**, without any external libs.

Comment: well, taking a look at draggable (or some similar library's) source code would probably be instructive and helpful, since they've already solved it. And it's open source so you can take any bits you need without worry. Draggable obviously requires base jQuery but all jQuery functions are of course, ultimately, implemented in native JS, so it should be possible to remove the jQuery syntax from it and replace with all-native JS. Although it seems like a huge effort - what's the objection to external libs, really?

Comment: I've tried to tackle this a couple of times -- and it's a lot of code :P ultimately I think you want to track the position of the cursor and update that `.handle` span as the cursor changes.  So, if the cursor moves 10 pixels to the right, add 10 pixels to the span's left style property (and then there's the fun of setting boundaries against the parent container's dimensions to make sure you don't go too far)

Comment: IMO, most of these "I >need< to do this without any libs" cases are programmers self-pride or he/she is just lazy when it comes to read documentation or see examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit and changed the selectors from class to ID. I also would advice you to use external libraries to make it more easy for you. Besides that I also removed the event listeners inside your HTML and translate them to Javascript.  Is this what you want?

```js
window.onload = addListeners();

function addListeners(){
    document.getElementById('handle').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

function mouseUp()
{
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', spanMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e){
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', spanMove, true);
}

function spanMove(e){
  var bar = document.getElementById('bar')
    var span = document.getElementById('handle');   
    
    // variables 
    var bar_width = bar.offsetWidth; 
    var handle_width = span.offsetWidth;
    
    // stop scroll left if the minimum and maximum is reached
    if(e.clientX < bar_width - handle_width - 1 && e.clientX > 1){
    span.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    }
}
```

```css
#bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

#handle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 2px;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <span id="handle"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, following solution works perfectly on last version of Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Edge Chromium.

```js
window.onload = addListeners();
   
function addListeners()
    {
    var div = document.getElementById('div');
    var span = document.getElementById('span');   
            
    span.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
    
    //compute space between left border of <div> and left border of <span>
    // this value is also used to compute space at right
    iMinLeft = span.offsetLeft;  
    // compute max left value allowed so that span remains in <div>
    iMaxLeft = div.clientWidth - span.offsetWidth - iMinLeft; 
    }

function onMouseDown(e)
    {
    if (e.which === 1) // left button is pressed
        {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, true);
        // save mouse X position to compute deplacement
        posMouseX = e.clientX;
        span.style.background = "yellow";
        }
    }

function onMouseMove(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //compute mouse deplacement
    deltaX = posMouseX - e.clientX;

    //compute new left position of <span> element
    iNewLeft = span.offsetLeft - deltaX;
   
    if (iNewLeft < iMinLeft) 
        {
        iNewLeft = iMinLeft;
        }
    else
        {
        if (iNewLeft > iMaxLeft) 
            {
            iNewLeft = iMaxLeft;
            }
        }
    
    span.style.left = iNewLeft + 'px';

    // save mouse X position to compute NEXT deplacement
    posMouseX = e.clientX;
    }
    
function onMouseUp(e)
    {
    if (e.which === 1) // left button is pressed
        {
        e.preventDefault();
        span.style.background = "white";
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, true);
        }
    }
```

```css
#div 
    {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    }
#span
    {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    left: 2px;
    top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div id="div">
    <span id="span">&#x1F603</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript line `e.preventDefault();` is necessary to avoid `<span>` to become 'blue' when dragging.

CSS code `cursor: pointer;` is only to see that unicode is clickable.

Javascript line `if (e.which === 1)` has been added to prevent emoticon to move when `RIGHT` mouse button is clicked.

The rectangle around emoticon when `<span>` is dragged move without being shifted (see previous solution) and space remaining in left or in right are equal.

Thanks to [w3schools-exemple](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_draggable)